# exp_date=Thu Sep 9 14:06:38 UTC 2021 reduce 30 days from exp_date in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

exp_date=Thu Sep 9 14:06:38 UTC 2021  reduce 30 days from exp_date in shell script

I know from current date I can use this  date --date "30 days ago"  But when I try it from a date variable to do the same its not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `date` to get your date in epoch seconds.
2. Subtract 30 days of seconds.
3. Convert the epoch seconds to ... whatever you need:

   ```
    root@pi:~# date
    Sun 19 Sep 2021 04:07:01 PM CDT
    root@pi:~# date -d @$(( $(date -d 'Wed Nov 13 14:06:38 UTC 1954' +%s) - 30*86400 ))
    Thu 14 Oct 1954 08:06:38 AM CST
   ```